# Paired T-Test Question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

If you have two paired groups (group A and B) and want to determine the difference in the two means, you would use a t test for two related populations. However, what if you want to determine the % increase or decrease for group B rather than the difference in the means for the two groups (i.e. determine the % increase/decrease in the average price across the two related groups)? Would we be able to do this with a matched pair t-test?

Comment: *determine the % increase or decrease for group B* sounds like estimation, not testing. Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just want to determine the % change between the two groups (which are matched pairs for before/after data). If it's an estimation problem, would I need to calculate the % change for each of the pairs and then use that data to calculate a confidence interval? Apologies if this is a silly question - I'm new to statistics.

Comment: There is an issue of what you mean by "% change:" would it reflect the ratio of the *mean value* in B relative to the mean value in A, or would it be the *mean ratios* among all the pairs?  The two values almost always differ and have different meanings.